# What are possible exceptions can be thrown while running executeQuery()

Tags: java

I'm running JConnector to get data from database( I use mysql ). I checked my data from running a query from Secure Shell, it worked fine. However, it threw NullPointerException when I run my program, it only read the first row. I have just learned Java for a month, so sorry if my question sounds strange to you guys.
This is my code:

```
    private void loadNodesFromDatabase()
    {
        Statement stmt = Database.connect();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Node";
        ResultSet res;
        try 
        {
            res = stmt.executeQuery( query );
            while( res.next() ) 
            {
                Integer id = res.getInt( "Id" );
                String position = res.getString( "Position" );
                String rule = res.getString(  "RuleOnMap" );
                Integer foodTax = res.getInt(  "FoodTax" );
                boolean mapValue = res.getBoolean( "MapValue" );

                Node n = new Node( id, PointOnGraph.parse( position ), Node.RuleOnMap.valueOf( rule ), foodTax, mapValue );
                System.out.println( n );
                nodes.add( n );
            }
            res.close();
         }
         catch( Exception e ) 
         { 
             System.out.println( "Selection Error:  " + e );  
         }  
    }
```

This is the query that I created my table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Node (Id INT(3), Position VARCHAR(12),  RuleOnMap VARCHAR(6), FoodTax INT(2), MapValue TINYINT(1), PRIMARY KEY(Id));
```

And this is the error message from Eclipse:

```
( 1, '20,20,88', PAY, 10, false )
Selection Error:  java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

Thanks,

After calling e.printStackTrace();

```
 ( 1, '20,20,88', PAY, 10, true )
Selection Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.Game.loadNodesFromDatabase(Game.java:177)
    at Game.Game.<init>(Game.java:31)
    at Test.GameLoadDatabseTest.loadNodesTest(GameLoadDatabseTest.java:30)
    at Program.main(Program.java:39)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.GameLoadDatabseTest.loadNodesTest(GameLoadDatabseTest.java:32)
    at Program.main(Program.java:39)
```

Best regards,
Chan Nguyen

Comment: Hi Chan, can you tell us from what line the exception is thrown? It should say in the message (otherwise post the first few lines of the exception here). Also, is the exception thrown after one node has been read, or before?

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for reading. After it read the first one( i.e. in the while loop ), the exception threw.

Comment: No, he catches the exception and prints it using `System.out.println(...)` which will only call the `Exception.toString()` method, that defaults to the class name and the message, it does not include the stack trace. If you want to print the stack trace you have to use `e.printStackTrace()` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like first `n` is printed out, right?

In this case my bet is that `nodes` is `null`. Did you forget to initialize the List?

Comment: ^_^ ! Exactly my problem ;) ! You have a such an incredible guess! Great thanks Peter!

Comment: Note: don't catch generic Exception. Always only catch the concrete exception that can actually be thrown.